# Apache Hive multiple hive-site.xml for multiple metastore servers

Tags: hadoop, hive

what I'd like to do is to run multiple metastore servers on the same machine. In practive I'd like to have multiple HCatalog server running on the same machine each with its `hive-site.xml` file. How can I achive this?

My metadata store is an external Postgres database so I've configured the `hive-site.xml` accordingly and it works fine if I use a single metastore server.

What I want is to have different `hive-site.xml` files each with a different database connection (so that each metastore points to a different database server).

Do I have to specify a different classpath when running the HCatalog process where each path contains a `hive-site.xml` file?

Comment: **1.** if you use proper Metastore services, then use `hivemetastore-site.xml` for all properties that are specific to the service and should not leak to clients _(e.g. passwords to databases)_ **2.** yes, you will need different directories with different sets of XML files and set your CLASSPATHs to the appropriate directory -- that's what Cloudera Manager does for all service instances, for the record

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter thanks for the answer, anyway I'm running the server using the `hcat_server.sh` script. But there's a check if there's already an instance running, how can I overcome this? Do I have to run the server in a different way? For now what I've done is to modify the script in order to read the `HIVE_SITE_XML`  in order to be able to pass a custom configuration for each run.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how HCat works...